# Changing Flutter `launchUrl` webview animation direction

Tags: flutter, webview, url-launcher

Flutter `url_launcher` moves the web view from right to left, which is fine when a user is logged in to this Flutter app. But when a user is not logged in, I want a webview to slide up from the bottom like a modal since they will be on a log in page that should be perceived as a navigational dead end until they log in.

```
if (await canLaunchUrlString(url)) {
 await launchUrl(url);} else {
 throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

I don't see [any options](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/url_launcher-library.html) for this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

url_launcher doesn't offer much customizability in regards to webview.

You can define a webview page and then use the [page_transition](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition) package to transition between pages based on your condition.